# How to use python to save dict as a table in PDF with cell coloring?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pdf, colors

I have a dict variable to summary the errors of my experiments, which is defined as below:

```
my_dict= {' ': ['A error', 'B Error', 'C Error', 'D Error'], 'lab1': [0.34, 0.23, 80, 0.79], 'lab2': [0.53, 0.38, 96, 1.25], 'lab3': [0.40, 0.27, 68, 0.93]}
```

Is there a way in Python to save the above dict as a table in PDF?  Here, I hope to assign some thresholds to the values:  if error value is larger than threshold, the cell is red, otherwise, it is green.

For example, in the above table "my_dict", I hope to set different thresholds to different cells. Could someone provide some guidance on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disclaimer: I am the author of `pText`

You can use `pText` to create the PDF you described.
Let's start by creating an empty `Document`

```
    # create document
    pdf = Document()

    # add page
    page = Page()
    pdf.append_page(page)
```

We are going to use a layout-manager to determine where content needs to be. This is a lot easier than trying to figure out the PDF coordinate system ourselves.

```
    # set layout
    layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)
```

Next comes the fun part, actually working with your data:

```
    my_dict= {' ': ['A Error', 'B Error', 'C Error', 'D Error'],
              'lab1': [0.34, 0.23, 0.80, 0.79],
              'lab2': [0.53, 0.38, 0.96, 1.25],
              'lab3': [0.40, 0.27, 0.68, 0.93]}
```

I'm going to define a dictionary to map boundaries unto colors. You could easily change this piece of code to add more color, or change the colors.

```
    colors = {0: X11Color("Green"),
              0.25: X11Color("Yellow"),
              0.5: X11Color("Orange"),
              0.75: X11Color("Red")}
```

Next we create the `Table`

```
    table = Table(number_of_rows=4, number_of_columns=5)
```

Now we can call `add` on the table. Whenever we do, content is added at the current row (starting at the top row). If the row is full, we will automatically go to the next row.

```
    table.add(Paragraph(" "))
```

Now we add all the headers (I made them bold):

```
    for h in my_dict[" "]:
        table.add(Paragraph(text=h, font="Helvetica-Bold", font_size=Decimal(12)))
```

Next step is to actually add all your data to the `Table`:

```
    for name, row in [(k,v) for k,v in my_dict.items() if k != " "]:
        table.add(Paragraph(name))
        for v in row:
            c = X11Color("Green")
            for b,bc in colors.items():
                if v > b:
                    c = bc
            table.add(Paragraph(str(v),
                                font_color=c,
                                justification=Justification.CENTERED))
```

I am going to make the border on this `Table` a bit thinner than it would be by default:

```
    # set border
    table.set_border_width_on_all_cells(Decimal(0.2))
```

I am also going to add a `Paragraph` at the start of the `Page` to give some context as to what the table represents:

```
    # add to layout
    layout.add(Paragraph("This table contains all measurands for 3 lab-sessions."))
```

Now we add the `Table` to the `Page`

```
    layout.add(table)
```

Finally, we store the PDF:

```
    # attempt to store PDF
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as in_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(in_file_handle, pdf)
```

The final result looks like this (but you can play around with colors, fonts, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a pandas dataframe and then display a seaborn heatmap:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

my_dict= {' ': ['A error', 'B Error', 'C Error', 'D Error'], 'lab1': [0.34, 0.23, 80, 0.79], 'lab2': [0.53, 0.38, 96, 1.25], 'lab3': [0.40, 0.27, 68, 0.93]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df.set_index(' ', inplace=True)
sns.heatmap(df.T, cmap='RdYlGn', annot=True, cbar_kws={'label':'Error value'})
plt.savefig('Errors.pdf')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]